# redirecting subdomain to www gives page not found error

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, subdomain

On my vps plesk server I have created one domain mydomain.com and for that domain I have created subdomain as subdomain.mydomain.com    but if i redirect this subdomain to www.subdomain.mydomain.com using .htaccess file I gets an error as page could not be found . what must be the problem.

This is my .htaccess code to redirect

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is what my A host looks like

```
Host         Points To       TTL
@           166.xx.xx.yyy   600 seconds
admin       166.xx.xx.yyy   600 seconds
subdomain   166.xx.xx.yyy   1 Hour
```

Comment: do you have the DNS entry for the www.subdomain.mydomain.com set up?

Comment: I have dns entry for the subdomain.mydomain.com it works fine . Do i need to create dns entry sepearately for www redirect?

Comment: yes, you need another one for www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably missing a DNS entry for your `www.subdomain.mydomain.com` subdomain.

Add another A entry, for your "www" subdomain to point to your servers address, and it should work (if the virtualhost or alias is set up on the server correctly).

Comment: Currently this is wat my A host looks like     @   166.xx.xx.xx

Comment: you need A record for subdomain.mydomain.com to point to 166.x.x.x, and another A record for www.subdomain.mydomain.com to point to the same IP address (if both pages are served by the same server)

Comment: i have edited my question with the A host file .

Comment: where is the www.subdomain ? you need one for that too.